# Ways to block content online based on words?

Tags: web-filtering

Is there any way to block content online based on words from a blocklist?  I mean this very globally.  In other words, to remove a paragraph, page, or YouTube video suggestion (with its title), in any content (including photo captions, headlines, etc) if certain words from a blocklist are shown in it?

I generally use Firefox (and have used Greasemonkey scripts and Stylish), but would be willing to change browsers if that were the only way.

Comment: Reminds me of the 'clbuttic' issues that some sites had with these sorts of filters. I don't think you're going to be able to remove bits and pieces of pages without lots of work. You could certainly block things based on URL though. But why do you want to do that ?

Comment: @Lawrence It's for someone with something like a PTSD condition and certain content is a psychological trigger, and such content could (and does) appear almost anywhere, so blocking by URL is not good enough.

Comment: You will need to setup a proxy server to do what you want. What is the environment that the user will be using ? Always on one computer ? in a home network ?

Comment: @Lawrence It'd be fine to start with one computer that's connected wirelessly to a router in the home.  But if it could be done for any computer or tablet in that house in one shot, that'd be ideal.

Comment: The only way would be to do it for all computers in one shot. You'll need a separate computer to act as a proxy between the internet and your existing wireless router though.

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks.  That sounds like a lot of work; more than I expected.  I'm surprised this can't be done in the browser (per computer) with an add-on that scans the content and blocks elements that contain the blocklist words, sort of like AdBlock.  Can it?

Comment: If there is a plugin that's already written, sure ! Though I haven't come across a plugin with this sort of granularity. If you have the know how, you could certainly write one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Privoxy is the way to go.It is a non-caching web proxy built specifically for web filtering. I am not used to it but just to quote from its [user manual](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/quickstart.html):

*...Filters are a way of filtering or modifying what is actually on the page. An example filter usage: a text replacement of "no-no" for "nasty-word". That is a very simple example. This process can be used for ad blocking....*

Hope it helps.

Comment: Another option is to use a DNS protection service such as OpenDNS that filters inappropriate content.Also, parental control module in Kaspersky may also help.

Comment: the open DNS can not filter a YouTube age-restricted videos, so a word filtering is better